# difference between creating on-premise-gateway from Azure-portal and by downloading from the link as given in the description

Tags: azure, ssas, onpremises-gateway

I configured on-premise date gateway by downloading and installing from the Microsoft Azure-analysis documentation which I published below. However, I also found an option to create the same from Microsoft Azure-analysis portal.

Here I am trying to understand the difference before I attempt to create from Azure-portal. Would any please help me understand. Thank you for giving your valuable time.
[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Those are separate steps for configuring a gateway for use with Azure Analysis Services. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [David Browne - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members

**Gateway created from (as per your screen shot):** On-premises Data gateway that you can create from portal (as per your screen shot), Allows access to your on-premises data for Logic Apps service through the data gateway.
reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection

**Gateway created from Azure analysis page:** The on-premises data gateway provides secure data transfer between on-premises data sources and your Azure Analysis Services servers in the cloud. Those are separate steps for configuring a gateway for use with Azure Analysis Services
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway